How to have a full screen view act like a dialog in Android Studio
I'm new to Android Studio, I want to make a feature like this:
enter image description here
When I click on the feed button, a screen will slide from the right to full screen like this:
enter image description here
And when I press return, it will return to previous screen. All states, scroll position,... of the previous screen are still preserved. I'm confused whether this is kind of Dialog or Fragment or else.
How can I achieve something like that in Android Studio?
Thank for helping me.

Fragments will be the option. Create a fragment and use navigation to navigate to that fragment.

Have you read through the documentation and made an effort to get something started? https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/principles

I believe it should be better to use a separate activity, e.g. "FeedsActivity", with transition animtaions.
You can also do it via Fragment, though you'll need some extra logic to handle the AppBar title and back action
